# Relation between continuity and differentiability

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I have noticed that authors of introductory analysis textbooks always show that a function f is continuous at a point before trying to prove that it is differentiable there. Ahlfors, for instance, does this in "Complex Analysis: An Introduction to The Theory of Analytic Functions of One Complex Variable" when he proves the extended Cauchy's integral formula by induction:
[Check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ltimd.png)

Bartle does the same when proving the second form of the Fundamental theorem of calculus in "Introduction to Analysis". Is it always necessary to prove continuity at a point before showing that a function is differentiable there? Why? (Please provide a technical explanation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being differentiable in a point is stronger than being continuous in that point (this means that being differentiable in a point *implies* being continuous in that point)
Hence it is just make sense to start from the simpler attribute.
Moreover, (maybe someone will correct me here),
as being differentiable means (at least in the common cases) that the following exists:
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
then, the logical requirement is that when $h$ goes to $0$ you want $f(x+h)$ to become close to $f(x)$, and that is continuity.

Answer (score 1):

No, you prove a function differentiable by evaluating the limit

$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$ and differentiability *implies* continuity (and not conversely, as the function $|x|$ at $x=0$ shows).

---

By contraposition, a discontinuous function is not differentiable, and proving the first may be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Differentiability implies continuity: since
$$
\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x-x_0} 
$$
exists, $f(x) \to f(x_0)$ when $x\to x_0$. If not, then the limit does not exist, because
$$
\lim_{x\to x_0} x-x_0 = 0.
$$
So it’s not really necessary to check continuity first, but technically it’s often inevitable.

Comment: Ok, but I'm not talking about checking anything here, but rather writing a formal proof. In other words,  why authors prove that a function is continuous at a point before showing that it has a derivative there?

Comment: @DougL try to go your own way :) as you can see, there’s no obstacles. On the other hand, it is a common phenomenon in math, when some strong results are obtained from some weaker ones. I mean, it is better sometimes to go a long way, especially when you study basics.

Answer (score 0):

If a function is not continuous at a point $a$, it not differentiable at that point. Continuity does not guarantee differentiability, but continuity *is* necessary. If the function is not continuous, it's not differentiable, so checking for continuity can provide a preliminary check.

Comment: You are saying that "checking for continuity can provide a preliminary check", does that imply that it is not required to show continuity first when writing a formal proof? Then why do so many textbooks do this?